# Word doesn't reflect the change language for correction

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, autocorrect

I want to change the language settings for correction in Microsoft Word 2007. When I change it or even set it as standard, it doesn't save it.

I'm about to have a nervous breakdown.

How do I set and keep the language settings for correction in Microsoft Word 2007?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set English (UK) as default editing language in Word 2007?](http://superuser.com/questions/86898/how-to-set-english-uk-as-default-editing-language-in-word-2007)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your normal.dotm file (which can be found at C:\Users\[username]\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates on Windows Vista)

Comment: yep - just open it with Word, make the changes from the Options panel, and save :)

Comment: I think this is a solution of this also http://superuser.com/questions/86898/how-to-set-english-uk-as-default-editing-language-in-word-2007